# How to get State name from Latitude and Longitude in India

Tags: python, google-maps, reverse-geocoding, reversegeocodelocation

I know this is asked before, but my problem is different. I don't want to use any map provider like Google, Here since the number of co-ordinates I want to get state is huge (30,000 to 40,000).

I am curious that there should be any static library (Python) that will give this crude "State" information, which will be more than enough.

Since we know the lat, long boundaries of each state, anybody created any library where I can get state names from a pair of latitude and longitude?

My problem is that I can't reverse geo-code 30,000 ~ 40,000 points with a free account and I need only State information nothing else.

Comment: If you can get a shapefile of the states in India, which you can probably find on the internet, you can probably just code it yourself without too much effort.

Comment: @P.Leibner Thanks, I searched the internet and found shapefile of different extensions (.kml, .shp) which one should I work with? Can you recommend any documentation to learn these things?

Comment: proof of concept webpage using KMZ: http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygonKmzParsed_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/gadm36_IND_1w.kmz (takes a while to load, the KMZ is 4M), if you import the state polygons into a GIS aware database, in will be quicker.

Comment: I found Indian states shapefile .shp and with the help of one python shapefile processing library I am able to reverse geocode it, with very little delay. Thank you @P.Leibner for the ide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the shapefile from:
https://www.igismap.com/download-india-boundary-shapefile-free-states-boundary-assembly-constituencies-village-boundaries/

Use this python library to simply get the Indian State. It is very easy.
https://github.com/vis4/pyshpgeocode